# Dummy node for Traveling Salesman Problem

Tags: python, arrays, list, algorithm

Recently I have been reading a lot about TSP, and I need to create a variation of TSP where

1. I don't care about starting point (can be any city) and
2. The ending city does not need to be the same as starting city

Apparently, this can be achieved using a dummy node - with distance of 0 to every other node: [source](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/43549/what-tsp-variant-doesnt-return-to-start-point)
Does it mean that with input:  `cityA`, `cityB`, `cityC`, `cityD`, `cityE`  the matrix representation should look like:

```
[
[0,9,6,1,3]
[9,0,4,2,1]
[6,4,0,9,1]
[1,2,9,0,8]
[3,1,1,8,0]
[0,0,0,0,0]
]
```

Is this the correct way, if not then why? I am still confused about understanding why does the extra dummy node work in order to get the path with my variation. Thank you

Comment: Should your array have one extra column of all 0?

Comment: Aside from that, I don't think a dummy node is strictly necessary.  I would say create a DP solution that returns the shortest path after trying all paths from the current location.  The exit condition will just be once all cities have been visited return 0.  or return 0, [] if you want to build the path too.  Then run the DP function once for every possible starting position.  Using the dummy node is equivalent to this, except you would only run the DP function once and choose the dummy node as the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comment above, here is an example without the dummy node:

```py
import functools
import math

def shortest_path(arr):
    
    n = len(arr)
    bitmask = [1 << i for i in range(n)]
    target = (1 << n) - 1
    
    @functools.lru_cache(None)
    def helper(city, visited):
        nonlocal target, n
        
        if visited == target:
            return 0, [city]
        
        best = math.inf, []
        for neigh in range(n):
            if not (visited & bitmask[neigh]):
                cost, path = helper(neigh, visited | bitmask[neigh])
                cost += arr[city][neigh]
                path = [city] + path
                if cost < best[0]:
                    best = cost, path
        return best
    
    best, best_path = math.inf, []
    for start in range(n):
        total_distance, path = helper(start, bitmask[start])
        if total_distance < best:
            best, best_path = total_distance, path
    
    return best, best_path

def shortest_path_padded(arr):
    n = len(arr)
    bitmask = [1 << i for i in range(n)]
    target = (1 << n) - 1
    
    @functools.lru_cache(None)
    def helper(city, visited):
        nonlocal target, n
        
        if visited == target:
            return 0, [city]
        
        best = math.inf, []
        for neigh in range(n):
            if not (visited & bitmask[neigh]):
                cost, path = helper(neigh, visited | bitmask[neigh])
                cost += arr[city][neigh]
                path = [city] + path
                if cost < best[0]:
                    best = cost, path
        return best
    
    return helper(0, bitmask[0])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    arr = [
            [0,9,6,1,3],
            [9,0,4,2,1],
            [6,4,0,9,1],
            [1,2,9,0,8],
            [3,1,1,8,0]
          ]
    arr2 = [[0]*(len(arr[0])+1)] + [[0] + row for row in arr]
    
    print(shortest_path(arr))
    print(shortest_path_padded(arr2))
```

```
Out: (5, [0, 3, 1, 4, 2])
Out: (5, [0, 1, 4, 2, 5, 3]) # city names + 1 because city 0 is dummy city
```

> What's different between using a dummy node versus trying every city as the start city?

Nothing really, if you start at a dummy node 0 distance from any other city, the first choice it has will be to choose the first city to go to.

This solution without the for-loop and a zero-padded array will be the same as the solution with the for-loop and the array as is.

---

```py
#NO LIBRARIES
def shortest_path_padded_no_libs(arr):
    n = len(arr)
    bitmask = [1 << i for i in range(n)]
    target = (1 << n) - 1
    
    def helper(city, visited):
        nonlocal target, n
        
        h = (city, visited)
        if h in memo:
            return memo[h]
        
        if visited == target:
            return 0, [city]
        
        best = float('inf'), []
        for neigh in range(n):
            if not (visited & bitmask[neigh]):
                cost, path = helper(neigh, visited | bitmask[neigh])
                cost += arr[city][neigh]
                path = [city] + path
                if cost < best[0]:
                    best = cost, path
                    
        memo[h] = best
        return best
    
    memo = {}
    
    return helper(0, bitmask[0])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    arr = [
            [0,9,6,1,3],
            [9,0,4,2,1],
            [6,4,0,9,1],
            [1,2,9,0,8],
            [3,1,1,8,0]
          ]
    arr2 = [[0]*(len(arr[0])+1)] + [[0] + row for row in arr]
    print(shortest_path_padded_no_libs(arr2))
```

Comment: I see, thank you, I am gonna add a column full of 0 to make it 6x6 matrix, regarding this, I am using ant heuristics to optimize the problem, here is a link to a code that I am using: https://github.com/Vampboy/Ant-Colony-Optimization/blob/master/AntColony_python3_code.py

Comment: So in this case how would I do the 'iterations' to start from any city?

Comment: The iterations part should take care of itself as long as you pass the adjacency matrix as shown into `shortest_path`.  Note, I also added `shortest_path_padded` (with all zeros in the first row and column) which finds the shortest path using the dummy node approach you mentioned.  They should be equivalent.  Whichever one is easier for you to implement should be fine.

Comment: thank you so much for this, and can I just ask what is the computational cost of your algorithm - cuz it's not brute force right, it is feasible with 20+ cities?

Comment: 20+... probably not I would say 20 is the limit.

Comment: When adding in the dynamic programming aspect using the `@functools.lru_cache` wrapper we bring the computation time down from O(n!) to O(n^2 * 2^n).

Comment: If you're interested in TSP, I created a repo just playing around with trying to invent a new heuristic for it a while back: https://github.com/LPRowe/traveling-salesman-problem  This brings the time complexity down from O(n^2 * 2^n to O(n * 2^k * k^2) which works for more nodes so long as k is a reasonable size (k <= 12).

Comment: EDIT: Hi LPR, that is amazing!Thank you so much, unfortunately since this is a school project I am not able to use external libraries (which doesn't make any sense cuz in real life you use libraries which will make your life easier). Anyway, I tried to add a dummy node as you mentioned with the correct amount of zeros, but I am getting an error on that, here is the code: https://pastebin.com/5n6MfmYw The error is that the pheromone and visibility features are zeros and for some reason my algorithm then doesn't know how to cope with it. Is it even possible to have dummy nodes in ants colony opt

Comment: I would be extremely helpful if you could help me out, I am becoming desperate... What I tried and it kinda worked is when the dummy node consisted of [0,9999,9999,9999,9999,0] such that only the first and last city had 0s and others had 'infinity' but I guess this is not optimal solution

Comment: I updated the solution so that it doesn't use any libraries.  Although as a note, both `functools` and `math` are built into python.  At a glance, it looks like you added the dummy city as the last city.  Try changing the array so that the first column and first row are all zeros instead - this will match the solution provided above.

Comment: thank you so much again, now I fully understand the concept, and I practiced using your example. However, using the brute force method is not feasible because we are being assessed against a dataset that contains up to 25 nodes, that's why I belive that the ant optimization can come in handy. I updated my code so that the dummy node is in the beginning as you suggested: https://pastebin.com/UjbjrJbr however the error is still the same as before (it didn't have any impact as far as i am aware) I am still getting ```IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0```

Comment: again thank you so so much for everything!

Comment: Hmm... It looks like the bug is originates somewhere in the section where you preprocess  the matrix as opposed to where you solve for the shortest path.  That said, I would need to understand your project in much greater detail to be able to give any meaningful advice - which I unfortunately can't do at the moment.  You can however try this site https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ which might be able to help in that area.

Comment: Also, you mentioned that your data set will contain up to 25 nodes.  When there are more than 20 nodes, even the optimized solution to TSP is going to take a long long time.  So what people usually do is create some heuristic that approximates the best solution.  There are a bunch of heuristics that already exist - a popular one is to use a minimum spanning tree followed by a depth first search. These heuristics sacrifice some optimality - give a slightly longer than shortest path solution - but run much much faster typically between O(nlogn) and O(n^2) meaning they can easily handle 25 nodes.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you very much, so lastly, do you suppose that I should work on the ant colony heuristics or the minimum spanning tree heuristics. The latter seems easier, and I could probably understand it better - and then can write a more accurate report. But performance-wise, are these two heuristics similar (for instance time complexity wise)

Comment: It's up to you which path you choose to take.  I had never heard of ant colony optimization (ACO) before today.  It sounds interesting though, so I'll definitely read up on it in the future.  According to this paper (https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/11903697_65) ACO can be done in O(n^2) time complexity which is a little slower than the minimum spanning tree (MST) approach O(nlogn) although, depending on how you implement MST it could also be O(n^2).  Either way the time complexity is a moot point.  Unless you are dealing with more than 1,000 nodes both methods will work just fine.

Comment: If you're already familiar with how to make a minimum spanning tree and the basic pre/in/post order traversals of trees, then the MST plus traversal approach will definitely be easier.  Here's a link that discusses it: https://aswani.ieor.berkeley.edu/teaching/FA13/151/lecture_notes/ieor151_lec17.pdf

Comment: The last point to consider is that heuristic approaches do not guarantee an optimal solution.  So the ACO might have less error than the MST.  I'm not sure what that error is for ACO, but for MST it is typically 15% longer than the optimal path length, and could be at worst twice as long as the optimal path lenght.